# Probability of selected ball color

Tags: probability, statistics

You are on a game show. There are 3 bins in front of you labelled , , , with bin  having 1 white balls and 1 black ball, bin  have 3 White and 2 Black balls, and bin  having 5 White and 2 black balls. Without you seeing, the game show host chooses one of the bins at random (so that bin  gets selected with probability 1/3, the same for bins , ) and then selects a ball at random from the bin selected.

a) What is the probability the ball selected by the game show host is White?
b) Conditional on the event that the ball selected is White, what is the chance the game show host selected bin  was selected?

I am honestly very lost on both of these questions- I think we'd have to do the probability of the white over the probability of all outcomes for a, which I think could be (1/3)(1/2) + (1/3)(3/5) + (1/3)(5/7) = 127/210. For b. (5/7)(1/3)/(127/210). Can anyone let me know if I'm doing something wrong, and how I should go about the problem?

Comment: Both of your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is best answered using a tree diagram as below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to a) is correct. For b), consider the Baye's Theorem
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P(\{\text{the game show host selected bin }\}|\{\text{the ball selected is White}\})\\
=&\frac{P(\{\text{the game show host selected bin }\},\{\text{the ball selected is White}\})}{P(\{\text{the ball selected is White}\})}
\end{aligned}
$$

You compute the bottom part in (a) and the upper pact is in your computation as well.

Comment: It looks like that's exactly what OP did, and both answers are correct, right?